# How do I install curl with ares enabled

Tags: ubuntu, curl, libcurl

I have curl installed on the latest ubuntu via apt-get and that works fine, however I've been reading about the blocking nature of the DNS lookups and discovered that it's slowing down my app.

I've done apt-get install libc-ares2 but I'm not sure how to tell curl to use that library when doing a lookup.

I posted this question to AskUbuntu but was told it was probably better here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the AskUbuntu are thinking that this is a programming question and not a configuration question.  The binary you fetched by your `apt-get` command was not compiled with libc-ares2 (as an external library or a linked library).  When you fetched `libc-ares2` you got your computer to the point where it might build the version of cURL you want [from source](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html), but now the real work has begun.

Commonly you would download the source and look for a file called README or INSTALL.  It will (hopefully) talk about a step that has a line like `./configure`.  From here you can specify compile time options.  It's also possible that the make file for cURL can auto-detect the presence of `libc-ares2` and include it in it's build.

However taking a look at the latest source release while there is no `INSTALL` file there is a `configure` script.  Look at it's source it has this line:

```
--enable-ares[=PATH]    Enable c-ares for DNS lookups
```

If you run this command from the source folder:

```
./configure --enable-ares && make && sudo make install
```

Then you have a shot at getting the curl build you want.  There may very likely be a lot of error messages related to other missing libraries or missing make and GCC.  That will be harder to resolve in this answer.

[Here is a page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112143117/http://curl.haxx.se/dev/readme-ares.html) on cURL's project homepage that talks you through these steps

Comment: Thanks I've configured and installed curl with the right library just need to point curl to that correct install I guess

Comment: I was able to compile curl with `--enable-ares` but using `/usr/local/bin/curl` with the option `--dns-servers` followed by a correct or wrong IP address does not seem to change DNS servers.
Edit: in fact https://web.archive.org/web/20150910114057/http://curl.haxx.se/dev/readme-ares.html says without path you have to put ares source folder in curl source folder and name it "ares". I noticed `/usr/local/bin/curl --version` displayed `WARNING: curl and libcurl versions do not match. Functionality may be affected.`. The error was fixed when running curl from source folder, in `src` subfolder.

Answer (score 9):

If you want installable `.deb` package instead of putting everything to `/usr/local`, do this:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep curl
sudo apt-get install libc-ares-dev build-essential
apt-get source curl
cd curl-*
```

This will download `curl` sources with Debian/Ubuntu build files and patches.

Edit file `debian/control`: add line `libc-ares-dev` to `Build-Depends`

Edit file `debian/rules`: remove `--enable-threaded-resolver` and add `--enable-ares` to `CONFIGURE_ARGS`

Optional: increase version number in the first line of `debian/changelog`, for example `7.38.0-4+deb8u5` to `7.38.0-4+deb8u6`, this way your package will not get overwritten when you install updates to your system.

Now run command

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b -j4
```

It will generate several .deb files after an unreasonably long compilation time, go drink coffee or something while it is compiling.

You can install your new `curl` with `c-ares` support using this command:

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i curl_*.deb libcurl3-*.deb libcurl4-openssl-dev*.deb
```

Comment: This was perfect for a situation where I needed to add c-ares to the `curl` running on a debian field server - without having to consider many other factors when compiling from scratch (including SSL libs, etc).   I did however end up commenting out these three lines in debian/rules : `#-cd debian/build-nss && dh_auto_test` , `#-cd debian/build-gnutls && dh_auto_test` , and `#-cd debian/build-nss && dh_auto_test` - the tests were just taking forever

Comment: During install, I got the error `dpkg: error processing archive libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libcurl3-gnutls/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libcurl3-gnutls:amd64` (I did not do the optional step, which is not a good practice I think since you will not get security updates).
Edit: it worked after uninstalling curl but the curl option `--dns-servers` does not seem to work.
@hmedia1 for the first line, I think you meant `-cd debian/build && dh_auto_test`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install ares separately. You can download it [here](http://c-ares.haxx.se/).
Once downloaded, build c-ares (where current working directory is "c-ares-${VERSION}"):

```
cd /path/to/c-ares-${VERSION}
./configure --prefix=/destination/path/for/ares/install (NOTE: if you specify a destination directory, it must exist already! If you don't specify a prefix, content should be install at location /usr/local/include/)
make
make install
```

[following this](http://curl.haxx.se/dev/readme-ares.html)

Now that ares is built, you can build libcurl using ares.  I had an issue referencing ares so I had to copy the ares source directly into libcurl. To do this, rename the 'include' directory created by 'make install' from configuring ares to 'ares'. Then, copy this directory to libcurl's root directory. You can now build libcurl with the ares option (where current working directory is libcurl):

```
cd /path/to/libcurl
./configure --enable-ares
```

Full example:

```
cd /User/${USER}/c-ares-1.10.0
mkdir installation
make clean
./configure --prefix=/User/${USER}/c-ares-1.10.0/installation
make
make install
mv installation/include installation/ares
cp installation/ares /User/${USER}/libcurl/
cd /User/${USER}/libcurl/
./configure --enable-ares
make
make install
```

**EDIT (6/30/2015):**

Know that if you're cross-compiling libcurl, you need to cross-compile c-ares with the same cross-compiler settings (--host option).

Hope this helps!