# libcurl with ares on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, curl, docker

I read [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466130/how-do-i-install-curl-with-ares-enabled)

But it answers how to compile curl. I know that.
I would like to replace libcurl package.

So when I will install software aptitude will know that libcurl exists.
When ubuntu will update then it should not overrite libcurl.

```
sudo checkinstall
```

not recommended but advertising by most posts

```
sudo make install
```

e.g. 
http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/

[How do I install curl with ares enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466130/how-do-i-install-curl-with-ares-enabled)

I wonder if it worth to use `docker` if I need `libcurl` with `ares` for single app.