# Setting DNS server to use with a Curl request

Tags: php, apache, curl, dns

I want to use a Smart DNS Proxy ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_DNS_proxy_server)) like [Unblock-Us](https://www.unblock-us.com/) to fetch content via Curl from a Netflix URL (just the HTML, not video content). The Smart DNS makes it appear I'm from any country I choose.

To do that I presume I need to set the DNS of my Apache server, just as I'd set it on my local machine.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if it can be done with the curl version used by PHP, but with the curl command, there is a `--dns-servers` option (https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/48b0ec28c5325b1d815f). However you need to compile curl with "ares" enabled (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466130/how-do-i-install-curl-with-ares-enabled). Then I guess you can execute the curl Linux command from PHP.