# How to resolve Curl::Err::ConnectionFailedError calling http_get method of ruby curb gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, libcurl, curb

when I call `http_get` method of curb gem like

```
Curl::Easy.http_get(url)
```

I am getting an exception

```
error='Curl::Err::ConnectionFailedError: Couldn't connect to server' duration=7805.63 view=0.00 db=1.33 remote_ip=127.0.0.1

  Curl::Err::ConnectionFailedError - Couldn't connect to server:
  curb (0.9.3) lib/curl/easy.rb:73:in `perform'
  curb (0.9.3) lib/curl/easy.rb:296:in `http'
  curb (0.9.3) lib/curl/easy.rb:296:in `http_get'
  curb (0.9.3) lib/curl/easy.rb:347:in `http_get' 
  () home/punitcse/projects/project-name/core/modulename/here.rb:30:in `block in route'
```

The issue is only producing in my system on other system it is working fine.I have tried various things to resolve this issue like I have rebuild the `curl` with `ares` as this link suggested [How do I install curl with ares enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466130/how-do-i-install-curl-with-ares-enabled) . I tried to debug the gem but could not completely understand why the error is coming.

Here is the output of curl version

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed.